# What component should I use to regulate power during runtime?

Tags: mosfet, current, pwm, switching, mosfet-driver

I have been thinking about a way to reduce heat produced by my resistive wire based on some user input. My circuit is basically a simple resistive wire and arduino, both powerd by Li-Ion battery pack rated for 20A max (voltage is 25,2V when fully charged -> max current flowing through the wire is around 9A). With those 9A I am getting the maximum power, but that's not what I want all the time. I thought that the best and most obvious way to do such thing is to use some high power mosfet. So I tried it with IRF520 mosfet with some small heatsink on it and regular PWM signal from arduino board. Long story short, I blew it :-). Is there any other way to do this without using some enormous coolers? Perhaps relay...

Thanks a ton,

Papouc

Comment: We need to see a schematic of the circuit you tried, with the MOSFET.

Comment: Is this wire intentionally for heating?

Comment: Yes, it is intended for heating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mosfet is probably not turning on all the way, and is thus acting as a resistor. You don't want this, because resistors generate tons of heat. That's probably what destroyed your mosfet. You want the current to STOP when it's off, and GO FULL BLAST when it's on.

So, you need what is called a logic-level mosfet, so you can turn it off and on quickly with your arduino. You may need one that can pass a high current. You may still need a heatsink. There are graphs in the datasheets of mosfets to describe its operating parameters, and how much current you can pass in particular situations.

Comment: The IRF520 needs roughly 10 V of Vgs to "GO FULL BLAST". It's also worth pointing out that the rated maximum current in that mode is 9.2 A, so OP's heater would be pushing it to the limit even when fully open.